# Why is my function only concating the first indexes to my array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

My function `addOn` should add two words as separate indexes to my array, `start`. It will find the last index of `start` and then search the array, `Arr`, for that index; it then concats (`.concat`) the two indexes after that original index, the last index of `start`, to `start`. It starts by first finding `.indexOf` starting at a random index, if that random index returns undefined, then it will start at the `.indexOf` at the zeroth index of `Arr`, and will, then, at least return the two indexes after the original location of the last index of the `start` array. **The function `addOn` is the third function, but all the code is needed to understand `addOn`.**

The problem is that it **always adds the first two indexes** `("Once ", "Upon ")`.

```
var ArrSpace = function (text){
  ArrText = text.split(" ");
  for(var i = 0; i < ArrText.length; i++)
    ArrText[i] = ArrText[i].concat(" ");
  return ArrText;
}
var randomStart = function(text){
  var ArraySpace = ArrSpace(text);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()* (ArraySpace.length -2));
  var Start = ArraySpace[random].concat(ArraySpace[random + 1].concat(ArraySpace[random+2]));
  return Start;
}
var addOn = function (text){
  var start = randomStart(text), last = start[start.length - 1], Arr = ArrSpace(text);
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random()* (Arr.length -2)), look = Arr.indexOf(last, random);
  start = start.concat(Arr[look + 1].concat(Arr[look + 2]));
  if (start[start.length - 2] == undefined || start[start.length - 1] == undefined){
    start.pop();
    start.pop();
    look = Arr.indexOf(last);
    start = start.concat(Arr[look + 1].concat(Arr[look + 2]));
  }
  return start;
}

//  (text from: Poe's "The Raven")
var text = "Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary, Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore, While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping, As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door. T is some visiter, I muttered, tapping at my chamber door— Only this, and nothing more. Ah, distinctly I remember it was in the bleak December, And each separate dying ember wrought its ghost upon the floor. Eagerly I wished the morrow:—vainly I had sought to borrow From my books surcease of sorrow—sorrow for the lost Lenore— For the rare and radiant maiden whom the angels name Lenore— Nameless here for evermore. And the silken sad uncertain rustling of each purple curtain Thrilled me—filled me with fantastic terrors never felt before; So that now, to still the beating of my heart, I stood repeating T is some visiter entreating entrance at my chamber door Some late visiter entreating entrance at my chamber door;— This it is, and nothing more.";
console.log(addOn(text));
```

---

```
examples of the console.log:
late visiter entreating Once upon 
nodded, nearly napping, Once upon 
was in the Once upon 
each purple curtain Once upon 
rapping, rapping at Once upon
```

My script is taking words from a piece of text, but the words will not be in the same order as in the text every time, three words will be in the same order, it will search for the location of the last word and will maybe find it in a different place in the text and that is where the difference is. So far, it only places five words together; first three in order, and last three in order, but maybe not from the same place.  The last two words do not need to be different than earlier words, but the word before those two words must be the last word of start. That last word of start may be used more than once in the text.
I am planning for the `addOn` function to be repeated later. This is really meant to be used on larger texts.

I still do not understand my bug, it might be in the concatenating, the `.indexOf`, or someplace else?

Comment: Could you please state clearly what is that you are trying to do? (not what your script is doing)

Comment: @Michal, My script is taking words from a piece of text, but the words will not be in the same order as in the text every time, three words will be in the same order, it will search for the location of the last word and will maybe find it in a different place in the text and that is where the difference is. So far, it only places five words together; first three in order, and last three in order, but maybe not from the same place.

Comment: so pick three words in order and add two random words at the end (the end words must be different to the other three)?

Comment: @Michal, the end words do not need to be different, but the word before those two words must be the last word of start. That last word of start may be used more than once in the text.

Comment: By convention, variables starting with a capital letter indicate constructor functions (or constants if all caps). Your variables should all start with lower case letters.

Comment: @RobG, It will not return a negative number, it is multiplying Math.random() by two less than the length and then rounds down. The only way that it would get a negative number is if the length is less than two. All this is because ArraySpace.length and -2 are in parentheses.

Comment: Well, @RobG, it is multiplying Math,random() by two less than the length, so it is not subtracting two afterward. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No need to appologise for my error…

Comment: Try `x.concat(y).concat(z)` instead of `x.concat(y.concat(z))` (or `x.concat([y, z])`).

Comment: @torazaburo, I changed all of my `x.concat(y.concat(z))` to `x.concat(y).concat(z)`, but I still get the same result. Thanks for suggesting, though. :)

Comment: Your rollback is unwarranted. The title should be short and straight to the point. I did improve the clarity to help you get better answers, please read [Why can people edit my posts? How does editing work?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

Comment: @brasofilo, thanks for the input. I will agree to an edit, but I think the new stuff and the important stuff should be bolded, like the main question and the statis update; I also need to give credit for the text, or it would be plagiarism, it is not in its present state, but I will change back the title.

Comment: I passed the credit to a comment inside the code, just before Poe's text. It doesn't add any value to describing your problem.

Comment: @brasofilo, I have rolled back to your edit; Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want, but the "Once upon" is caused by `start = start.concat(Arr[look + 1].concat(Arr[look + 2]));` before `if-block`. If possible, could you use shorter sentence as a sample, then add an example of the expected result? It will be clearer for those who try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, I have finally found, is that after `.indexOf()`, I need to add `> -1`, so it looks like `.indexOf() > -1`